# Is it possible to send a script javascript/HTML instead of image file in MRAID complaint Ads?

Tags: html, mraid

I am thinking about sending an HTML/Javascript instead of image (creative) in an MRAID compatible Ad. Would the webview container display this correctly at the SDK/app end?

Comment: Do you mean you want to traffic an ad composed of HTML and JS rather than a simple image file?

Comment: Yes something like that.

Answer (score 1):

MRAID containers support JavaScript and HTML, and it is possible to traffic rich-media ads to them. Certain activities, like changing the size of the container, opening links, playing video, etc., can only be accomplished by using MRAID methods and events (called via JavaScript). The specification is available here:

http://www.iab.net/MRAID

You can test your code at the MRAID webtester:
http://webtester.mraid.org/

Comment: Do you know if it is common practice to use jQuery or JQLite in MRAID ads?

Comment: It's not uncommon at all, although it's best to try to minimize the weight of your ads and, more importantly, the number of network requests your ad makes.